page-break not working on headings ( python, weasyprint )
I want to create a pdf out of html content. I use beautifulsoup to get html string and then create PDF using weasyprint and python out of it.
I have issue when i want to show headings ( specifically h3 ) on a new page ( though this doesn't work for any of the h tags ). Now, I have this code in html
{% block report %}
<style>
h3 {
    page-break-before:always;
}
</style>
<div class="container" style="padding-top:45px">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <h1 id="h1-title" class="mb-5">{{report.title|safe}}</h1>
            <div class="control-head">
              <h3 id="1.-first-section">1. First Section</h3>
            <hr>
            <p>{{obj.some_content_one|safe}}</p>
          </div>
          
            <div class="control-head">
              <h3 id="2.-second-section">2. Second Section</h3>
            <hr>
              <p>{{obj.some_content_two|safe}}</p>
          </div>
          
            <div class="control-head">
              <h3 id="3.-third-section">3. Third Section</h3>
            <hr>
              <p>{{obj.some_content_three|safe}}</p>
          </div>
          
            <div class="control-head">
              <h3 id="4.-fourth-section">4. Fourth Section</h3>
              <hr>
              {{obj.some_content_four|safe}}
          </div>
          
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>

{% endblock report %}


And when i use page-break-after in h3 tags, weasyprint only renders content until this first h3 including the h3.string... If i use page-break-before: always; then weasyprint renders first "control-head" and {{obj.some_content_one|safe}} and stops rendering second at the end of the page where second h3 is ( it basically renders second control-head h3.string and content from {{obj.some_content_two|safe}} until it fills the page and then stops rendering pdf any further)..
I tried using page-break-after/before on table element and it worked ( these contents contain some tables ). It worked perfectly with both after/before options. But no matter what i do it won't work on headings.
I tried removing all the css i could find which affects h3 or .control-head but it just won't work. Not sure if it's important but i am also using Bootstrap5

The issue was fixed by removing
<div class="container" style="padding-top:45px">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
    ....
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

It didn't affect generated PDF layout at all and it allowed me to use page-break on headings
